# Cannot build .net core 1.1 with msbuild tools

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, .net-core, nuget-package, visual-studio-2017

I have a .net core class library I am attempting to build into a nugget package. however, on my build server (running team city), I am getting the following error:

> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3c6531587491c25e\MySolution\MyProject.csproj
>   error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

When I look in this directory, I ma missing the "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" folder from my build server. where do I get these tools without having to install visual studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

See the tracking issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1697

If you don't want to touch your build tools installation (by copying SDK files), you can also set the `MSBuildSDKsPath` environment variable to the location of the SDKs carried in the .net CLI (usually `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0\Sdks\`)

Comment: interesting. I gave up on this project for a bit to work on normal .net nuget packages. I'll give this a try when I complete that work

Comment: I am not seeing that is a directory (sdk\1.0.0.0\Sdk) but I am seeing (C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0\Sdks) with a BUNCH of directories. one of which is the Microsoft.NET.Sdk folder. should I point it to this directory? i'm going to give this a whirl...

Comment: Yes that one, typing it from memory probably wasn't the best idea